# How to turn off MAMP python interpreter

Tags: php, python, apache, mamp

I am writing a website where I show some code snippets in various languages.

The live version of the site is deployed in the cloud and displays the code correctly, while the local version I'm working on (which runs on MAMP on Windows with Apache 2.2.27) does not display the Python code.

The error log for Apache shows that:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=xxxx): Target WSGI script 'path/to/setup.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://localhost/mysite
```

which leads me to think that Apache is interpreting my python code, failing and returning a 500 error.

All that I could find online explains how to activate this functionality, but not what I should change if I want to disable it. I tried changing the extension of some python snippets and they are displayed, but that's a solution I don't like.

Is there a more elegant solution to prevent mod_wsgi from executing my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache data in the app settings or updating your OS.

Comment: Hi Dolby and welcome to StackOverflow! What would be the purpose of this operations? Can you please explain more?